# Computing the expectation for the coordinate wise minimum of a single multivariate normal draw

Tags: computational-statistics, multivariate-normal-distribution, extreme-value

Let $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu, \Sigma})$ be a $n$-dimensional multivariate normal random variable.

Are there efficient techniques for computing $\mathbb{E}(\min_i x_i)$?

The best I'm coming up with right now is straight MC integration, or maybe HMC sampling of the minimum itself, but I'm looking for something very fast, even if approximate.

Comment: How large an n? Is the special case of all mean elements being equal of any interest to you - that makes things easier. What about exchangeable (all mean elements equal, all diagonal elements equal, common non-negative correlation between all elements)? If exchangeable, E(min order statistic) = $\sigma \sqrt{1-\rho} E(\text{min order statistic of n iid N(0,1)}) + \mu$. (use pre-computed values). Afonja "The Moments of the Maximum of Correlated Normal and t-Variates" https://www.jstor.org/stable/2985184?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents may be good., but I've only seen the first page.

Comment: Roughly speaking $10 < n < 100$. No such luck with the variables, I need a fully general covariance matrix and a fully general mean vector.

Comment: The good news is that Afonja equation 3.1 has an explicit formula for E(max(general multivariate normal)), which should be easy to change to min by taking negative of the value for E(max()) using negative of $\mu$. The bad news is that it involves evaluation of standardized (i.e., N(0 vector, Identity matrix)) distribution function at arguments depending on (crunched down from) $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ in dimension as high as n-1. You can sign up for JSTOR for free and view the article on your bookshelf, which I recommend you do.

Comment: Variance reduction techniques might help. How about using min of n iid N(0,1) as a control variable? You can use precomputed value of E(min of n i.i.d N(0,1)) .  I have no idea how big the variance reduction might be - perhaps the amount of variance reduction depends on $\mu$ and $\Sigma$. Or maybe can use formula in my 1st comment for exchangeable r.v.s based on some kind of averaged $\sigma$ and $\rho$, it would make use of the same precomputed values of  E(min of n iid N(0,1)). There are probably a lot of variations you could try for control variable9s).

Comment: So if I follow Afonja, i still have to take an expectation over an orthant, correct? In which case we're back at doing HMC

Comment: I wrote " bad news is that it involves evaluation of standardized (i.e., N(0 vector, Identity matrix)) distribution function at arguments depending on (crunched down from) μ and Σ in dimension as high as n-1" so you get down to dimension n-1. That's why i gave the suggestion on control variables. Anyhow, how fast do you need to do the simulation - I think I did over 10 million replications per second for n = 100 in a very non-optimized set up. An approximate answer is good enough? Then give up a digit of accuracy in exchange for 100 time speedup. And this is all before any variance reduction.

Comment: I tried using min of n iid N(0,1) as a control variable.  Variance reduction ranges from 100% (i.e., perfect) when all mean elements are equal and covariance matrix  is a multiple of the Identity, to not very big when those conditions are far from being true. In terms of variance reduction, it is bad if the disparity in the mean vector is large relative to the covariance, If you had representative mean vectors and covariance matrices of interest, we could see what the actual variance reduction would be.  It's possible that using the exchangeable rv formula for control variable would do better.

Comment: If you had either a mean vector which is near mean vector of interest for several problems, or covariance matrix near covariance matrices for several problems, you could run a very large number of simulation replications once for the typical mean and covaarince to serve that "family" of problems.  Then use that as a control variable for the (nearby)  problems in that family. That could achieve good results if problems in the family aren't too far from what was run for the control variable. Good control variables intro in section 3 of http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/MCS04/MCS_var_red1.pdf

Comment: No such luck. My $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ can be all over the place.

Comment: Have you looked at the obvious thing of reducing the number of simulation replications to the maximum number you can do in the time available (time target) and determining whether the resulting accuracy is sufficient for your purpose?  Any variance reduction would then be "gravy', i.e., only make things better.

Comment: Yeah, my best bet right now is to take an empirical average over a fixed sample of vectors. Using the reparametrization trick, I can even make it differentiable wrt mu and Sigma, which is also desirable in my case.

Comment: Cab you write out in detail your approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution, but may help.

According to [extreme value theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory#Univariate_theory), the CDF for the coordinate-wise *maximum* is the joint CDF evaluated "isotropically", i.e.
$\Pr[\max_ix_i\leq X]=\Pr[x_1\leq X,\ldots,x_n\leq X]$.

Wikipedia gives a couple of [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) for numerically approximating a multivariate normal CDF:

Botev, Z. I. (2016). "The normal law under linear restrictions: simulation and estimation via minimax tilting". Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Statistical Methodology). [doi:10.1111/rssb.12162](https://dx.doi.org/10.1111%2Frssb.12162).

Genz, Alan (2009). Computation of Multivariate Normal and t Probabilities. [Springer](http://www.springer.com/statistics/computational+statistics/book/978-3-642-01688-2). ISBN 978-3-642-01689-9.

Comment: That's equivalent to integrating the mass of a multivariate normal across a given orthant, and afaik the best way to do that is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.4118.pdf

But that's slow, and I'll have to do it for all $X$ to compute my expectation !

Comment: OK. For approximation, I might look at computing sample PDFs for some cases of interest, and see how they look. For example, I could imagine the PDF might be reasonably approximated by using the i.i.d. extreme-value PDF, where you parameterize the dof's ("$n$") in terms of your covariance-matrix singular value spectrum.